# Use of a pronoun in a neither/nor construction

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis

> Neither Ms. Perez nor Ms. Yanaka believes that watching as much television as **her** son Sam does will lead to anything productive.

Is **her** correct? or should it be **their**?

Comment: This requires more context. Is the antecedent for *her* contained in the sentence or does it belong to a third party or parties mentioned in a previous sentence?

Comment: What @Robusto said. In the absence of further context, I think this is NARQ.

Answer (score 1):

Using *her* is ambiguous, as we have no way of determining which of the ladies Sam is the son of.

Using *their* is incorrect unless Sam is the son of both ladies.

The proper way to resolve the situation is to specify which one of them Sam is the son of, thus:

> Neither Ms. Perez nor Ms. Tanaka believes that watching as much TV as Ms. Perez's son Sam does will lead to anything productive.

Comment: Just want to remark, if it's clear from the context whose son Sam is, then __her__ is not ambiguous, and I think it reads more smoothly than your sentence too.

Comment: @MrLister: ...but then in all likelihood "Sam" would be enough, as opposed to "her son Sam". So the original sentence is probably infelicitous in any context.

Comment: Assuming of course that Ms Perez and Ms Yanaka are not lesbians married in common law, in which case *their* would indeed be correct ;-)

Comment: @spiceyokooko, regarding use of *their*, it seems to me a bit politically incorrect to assume Ms Perez and Ms Yanaka have to be lesbians married in common law; *ie* they might not be married, or they might be conjoined twins with a common womb, or might even not be lesbians at all!

Comment: @MrLister: That is true, but then it is used like a title, for the Lady Jessica is truly special!

Comment: @jwpat7: Your common womb must be the explanation! A perfectly reasonable context.

Comment: @jwpat Indeed! Doncha just love political correctivitus! I thought it was amusing that *their* could actually be correct in a certain context.

Answer (score 0):

"... *her* ..." is correct; *their* is not relevant.

The sentence makes sense in the context where it is referring to someone's son Sam, which someone would have been referred to already and is someone other than the two women named in the sentence. As in, maybe,

> Ms Yanrez was complaining about her children, telling Ms. Perez and Ms. Yanaka how her children watched too much TV. Neither Ms. Perez nor Ms. Yanaka believes that watching as much television as her son Sam does will lead to anything productive.